# Generic property getter in Linq

Tags: .net, linq, .net-3.5

I having a hierarchy collection object where I am trying to retrieve the last level object's property in Linq. I dont want to write a get method for every property. Not sure how to achieve it through selector

```
Class Test {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int PopertyA { get; set; }
    public string PopertyB { get; set; }
              ...Many more properties

}

public static TResult GetTest(hierarchyObject, int ID, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
{
    return (from level1 in hierarchyObject.Level1
            from test in level1.Test
            where test.ID.Equals(ID)
            select selector).First();
}
```

This dint work. Currently I have made the method to return the test object and accessing the properties in the calling method. But wanted to know if I can implement a generic property getter.

**Edit:**

```
Class Hierarcy{
  public IList<Level1> level1;
}

Class Level1 {
public IList<Test> test;
}
```

Given a hierachy object and test.ID, I want to retrieve any property of Test.

Comment: I've read this through 5 times and still don't understand what you're trying to do...

Comment: You didn't provide enough details. How is your "hierarchy" organized? What is the type of `Level1`? If there is a sub-property named `Level2` or `Level3`, what type is that? What does "last level" mean?

Comment: hierarchyObject has a collection of Level1 which has a collection of Test

Comment: Why do you use `Test.ID.Equals(ID)` (class member of `Test`) in the where clause, instead of `test.ID.Equals(ID)` (instance member of local variable `test`)?

Comment: Sorry, thats a typo it should be test.ID.Equals(ID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with your property. To avoid repeating the entire LINQ query for each and every property you are interested in, it would be better to get the Test object first, and then check its individual properties:

```
class Hierarcy
{
   public IList<Level1> Level1;
   public Test GetTest(int ID)
   {
       return this
          .Level1
          .SelectMany(level => level.Test)
          .Where(test => test.ID == ID)
          .First();
   }
}
```

Once you get the `Test` class, you have all its properties:

```
Test t = myHierarchy.GetTest(someId);

// do something
int i = test.PropertyA;
string s = text.PropertyB;
```

If you are interested in getting a value of a property dynamically, using its name only, you can do it using Reflection:

```
Test t = myHierarchy.GetTest(someId);

// this will print all properties and their values
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in t.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name:{0}, Value:{1}",
       pi.Name,
       pi.GetValue(pi, null));
}
```

In both examples, actual query is executed only once, which can be significant if there are lots of objects in your collections.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you might want something like this:

```
public static TResult GetTest(hierarchyObject, int ID, Func<Test, TResult> selector)
{
    return (from level1 in hierarchyObject.Level1
            from test in level1.Test
            where test.ID.Equals(ID)
            select selector(test)).First();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use method chain. You cant use query expression. At least for Select part. Rest can remain as query expression.

```
hiearchyObject.Level1.SelectMany(x=>x.Test).Where(test=>test.ID.Equals(ID)).Select(selector).First();
```

Dont have PC to test it now.

Also in method, you should either declare whole method as generic acording to selector (same generic parameters) or use `public static TResult GetTest<TResult> (.. , Func<Test, TResult> selector)`

Comment: can't he just do `select selector(test)`?

Comment: Because in your case it creates new method, that simply calls selector method. In my case, you are dirrectly calling using selector method.